# Angular chained HTTP Posts returns Error 402 but is caught as Error 504

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient, kong

I am trying to get the error message on the Error 402 returned by our API (***sent by kong API***) call, but my transaction service is catching the error as HTTP 504 when the browser shows an Error HTTP 402.

[It shows an Error 402 with a proper response, but my error message is showing as an Error 504](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsdT5.png)

my httpClient call is as follows:

```
sendCashOutRequest(transaction: Transaction): Promise<{ success: boolean, msg: string }> {
    let success = false;
    console.log("generating send request ...");
    const authUrl = environment.authAPI;
    const remittanceUrl = environment.sendMoneyAPI;
    const remittanceRequestBody = this.buildRemittanceRequestBody(transaction);
    this.showLoader();
    let resultToken;
    let sendPromise = new Promise<{ success: boolean, msg: string }>( (resolve,reject) => {
        //this will post to get authentication token
        this.authBearerService.getAuthToken().then( token => {
            resultToken = token
            console.log("First API call (auth request) : " + resultToken);
            return this.http.post(remittanceUrl, remittanceRequestBody, {
                observe: 'response',
                headers: new HttpHeaders()
                .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
                .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + resultToken),
                responseType: 'json'
            } ).toPromise()
            .then(
                resp2 => {
                    console.log("Successfully sent transfer request!", resp2);
                    //get response body                  
                    success = true;
                    this.hideLoader();
                    resolve( {success: success, msg: transaction.PayRefNo});
                }, 
                err => {
                    console.warn("Error encountered!!");
                    console.warn("has message body? ",err.body['message']);
                    reject( { success, msg: err.error.message });
                }
            ).catch( err => {
                console.log("Error in sending cash out request", err);
                reject( {success : success, msg : "Error connecting to Seven Connect services, Please try again"});
            });
        });
    });

    return sendPromise;
}
```

Is there something between the browser and the angular that it won't/can't catch the Error 402? Or Am I chaining my post request incorrectly?

Comment: See last line in your screenshot - there's another response with 504 status code.

Comment: yes it has another response. But i only made 2 post requests, wouldn't it have only 2 responses? does it mean my 2nd call got 2 responses?